# Docusign Envelope Custom Fields - Validation

Tags: docusignapi

When adding Envelope Custom fields there are two types - Free text and list (https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-document-labels)

Is is possible to add any rules to free text like 3 digits only, etc.? I know this is possible in custom document field but not sure how to implement on envelope custom fields.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE accept (check) the best answer to your questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Good idea but we don't have this feature in the DocuSign web tool or within the API.

But if you're sending the envelopes via the API, then your own application can enforce such rules and check the data supplied for conformance to your rules before creating the envelope.